# Верстка кнопки с нестандартной рамкой

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сверстать такую кнопку, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, не знаю, как лучше поступить. Вставить картинкой бэкграундом на фоне текста или можно как-то сверстать?

Если можно сверстать, подскажите, пожалуйста, как.

Понимаю, что нужно дать бордер правой стороне, верхней и нижней а слева через before добавить другой блок. Только вот не знаю, как этот блок сверстать...

```css
div {
margin: 50px;
}
a {
margin: 20px;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
border-top: 2px solid yellow;
border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
border-right: 2px solid yellow;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a>Кнопка</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
htnl,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: Blue;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin: 20px 70px;
  border: 4px solid Yellow;
  border-left: none;
  color: Yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -16px;
  top: -3px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 40px;
  border-left: 4px solid Yellow;
  border-bottom: 4px solid Yellow;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(39deg);
}

.btn::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: -12px;
  bottom: -4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid Yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  перейти сейчас!
</div>
```

SVG:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg fill="blue">
  <g>
    <polygon x="0" y="0" points="280,57 20,57 4,41 30,4 280,4 280,57" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="4"></polygon>
    <text x="76" y="35" fill="yellow" font-weight="bold">ПЕРЕЙТИ СЕЙЧАС!</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: А как сделать переходы более красивыми, а то они слегка не ровно сходятся сверху и снизу?

Comment: Да, действительно. Как ?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy либо долго подбирая ширину рамки и углы наклона, либо SVG, ответ немного дополнил